# hasChanges() == true at Appstart

Tags: breeze

Edit: JSON not complete, had to cut some

Somehow one Entity has EntityState "Added" when queried from the Server for the first time.
I create 3 users in the DBContextInitializer. This happens every time I start my app. It will be in State "Unchanged" if I call `Manager.rejectChanges()`, but I have to do this manually.

If i do not do that, and save another Entity (maybe Team/Order/OrderDetail) the specific User gets saved as a copy of its original Entity with a unique key but identical values like name and so on. I checked my code a dozen times if I might have forgotten something, but I do not invoke any change in state on this User-Entity anywhere.

This is a print of `Manager.getChanges` (EntityType of "User"):

```
[
[
    {
        "entityAspect": {
            "entityGroup": {
                "entityManager": {
                    "serviceName": "api/Breeze/",
                    "metadataStore": {
                        "namingConvention": {
                            "name": "noChange"
                        },
                        "localQueryComparisonOptions": {
                            "name": "caseInsensitiveSQL",
                            "isCaseSensitive": false,
                            "usesSql92CompliantStringComparison": true
                        },
                        "dataServices": [
                            {
                                "serviceName": "api/Breeze/",
                                "adapterName": null,
                                "hasServerMetadata": true
                            }
                        ],
                        "_resourceEntityTypeMap": {
                            "Mvls": "Mvl:#MAHN.Model",
                            "MvlOps": "MvlOP:#MAHN.Model",
                            "StatusOps": "StatusOP:#MAHN.Model",
                            "Teams": "Team:#MAHN.Model",
                            "TeamLeaders": "TeamLeaders:#MAHN.Model",
                            "Users": "User:#MAHN.Model",
                            "TeamUsers": "TeamUsers:#MAHN.Model",
                            "UserRoles": "UserRoles:#MAHN.Model",
                            "Roles": "Role:#MAHN.Model",
                            "TeamRoles": "TeamRoles:#MAHN.Model"
                        },
                        "_entityTypeResourceMap": {
                            "Mvl:#MAHN.Model": "Mvls",
                            "MvlOP:#MAHN.Model": "MvlOps",
                            "StatusOP:#MAHN.Model": "StatusOps",
                            "Team:#MAHN.Model": "Teams",
                            "TeamLeaders:#MAHN.Model": "TeamLeaders",
                            "User:#MAHN.Model": "Users",
                            "TeamUsers:#MAHN.Model": "TeamUsers",
                            "UserRoles:#MAHN.Model": "UserRoles",
                            "Role:#MAHN.Model": "Roles",
                            "TeamRoles:#MAHN.Model": "TeamRoles"
                        },
                        "_entityTypeMap": {
                          "User:#MAHN.Model": {
                                "name": "User:#MAHN.Model",
                                "shortName": "User",
                                "namespace": "MAHN.Model",
                                "defaultResourceName": "Users",
                                "dataProperties": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "UserId",
                                        "nameOnServer": "UserId",
                                        "dataType": "Int32",
                                        "isNullable": false,
                                        "defaultValue": 0,
                                        "validators": [
                                            {
                                                "validatorName": "required"
                                            },
                                            {
                                                "validatorName": "int32"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "isPartOfKey": true
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "UserName",
                                        "nameOnServer": "UserName",
                                        "dataType": "String",
                                        "isNullable": true,
                                        "fixedLength": false,
                                        "validators": [
                                            {
                                                "validatorName": "string"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "isPartOfKey": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Nachname",
                                        "nameOnServer": "Nachname",
                                        "dataType": "String",
                                        "isNullable": true,
                                        "fixedLength": false,
                                        "validators": [
                                            {
                                                "validatorName": "string"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "isPartOfKey": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "Vorname",
                                        "nameOnServer": "Vorname",
                                        "dataType": "String",
                                        "isNullable": true,
                                        "fixedLength": false,
                                        "validators": [
                                            {
                                                "validatorName": "string"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "isPartOfKey": false
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "OasisLogin",
                                        "nameOnServer": "OasisLogin",
                                        "dataType": "String",
                                        "isNullable": true,
                                        "fixedLength": false,
                                        "validators": [
                                            {
                                                "validatorName": "string"
                                            }
                                        ],
                                        "isPartOfKey": false
                                    }
                                ],
                                "navigationProperties": [
                                    {
                                        "name": "TeamUsers",
                                        "nameOnServer": "TeamUsers",
                                        "entityTypeName": "TeamUsers:#MAHN.Model",
                                        "isScalar": false,
                                        "associationName": "TeamUsers_User",
                                        "foreignKeyNames": [],
                                        "foreignKeyNamesOnServer": [],
                                        "validators": []
                                    },
                                    {
                                        "name": "UserRoles",
                                        "nameOnServer": "UserRoles",
                                        "entityTypeName": "UserRoles:#MAHN.Model",
                                        "isScalar": false,
                                        "associationName": "UserRoles_User",
                                        "foreignKeyNames": [],
                                        "foreignKeyNamesOnServer": [],
                                        "validators": []
                                    }
                                ],
                                "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity",
                                "validators": []
                            },


                        "Team:#MAHN.Model": {
                            "entityType": {
                                "name": "Team:#MAHN.Model",
                                "shortName": "Team",
                                "namespace": "MAHN.Model",
                                "defaultResourceName": "Teams",
                                "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity"
                            },
                            "_indexMap": {
                                "1": 1,
                                "2": 0,
                                "3": 2,
                                "4": 3
                            },
                            "_entities": [
                                {
                                    "entityAspect": {
                                        "entityState": {
                                            "_$typeName": "EntityState",
                                            "name": "Unchanged"
                                        },
                                        "isBeingSaved": false,
                                        "originalValues": {},
                                        "_validationErrors": {},
                                        "validationErrorsChanged": {
                                            "name": "validationErrorsChanged_entityAspect",
                                            "_nextUnsubKey": 1
                                        },
                                        "propertyChanged": {
                                            "name": "propertyChanged_entityAspect",
                                            "_nextUnsubKey": 1
                                        },
                                        "_entityKey": {
                                            "entityType": "Team:#MAHN.Model",
                                            "values": [
                                                2
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "wasLoaded": true
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "entityAspect": {
                                        "entityState": {
                                            "_$typeName": "EntityState",
                                            "name": "Unchanged"
                                        },
                                        "isBeingSaved": false,
                                        "originalValues": {},
                                        "_validationErrors": {},
                                        "validationErrorsChanged": {
                                            "name": "validationErrorsChanged_entityAspect",
                                            "_nextUnsubKey": 1
                                        },
                                        "propertyChanged": {
                                            "name": "propertyChanged_entityAspect",
                                            "_nextUnsubKey": 1
                                        },
                                        "_entityKey": {
                                            "entityType": "Team:#MAHN.Model",
                                            "values": [
                                                1
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "wasLoaded": true
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "entityAspect": {
                                        "entityState": {
                                            "_$typeName": "EntityState",
                                            "name": "Unchanged"
                                        },
                                        "isBeingSaved": false,
                                        "originalValues": {},
                                        "_validationErrors": {},
                                        "validationErrorsChanged": {
                                            "name": "validationErrorsChanged_entityAspect",
                                            "_nextUnsubKey": 1
                                        },
                                        "propertyChanged": {
                                            "name": "propertyChanged_entityAspect",
                                            "_nextUnsubKey": 1
                                        },
                                        "_entityKey": {
                                            "entityType": "Team:#MAHN.Model",
                                            "values": [
                                                3
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "wasLoaded": true
                                    }
                                },
                                {
                                    "entityAspect": {
                                        "entityState": {
                                            "_$typeName": "EntityState",
                                            "name": "Unchanged"
                                        },
                                        "isBeingSaved": false,
                                        "originalValues": {},
                                        "_validationErrors": {},
                                        "validationErrorsChanged": {
                                            "name": "validationErrorsChanged_entityAspect",
                                            "_nextUnsubKey": 1
                                        },
                                        "propertyChanged": {
                                            "name": "propertyChanged_entityAspect",
                                            "_nextUnsubKey": 1
                                        },
                                        "_entityKey": {
                                            "entityType": "Team:#MAHN.Model",
                                            "values": [
                                                4
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "wasLoaded": true
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "_emptyIndexes": []
                        },
                        "TeamLeaders:#MAHN.Model": {
                            "entityType": {
                                "name": "TeamLeaders:#MAHN.Model",
                                "shortName": "TeamLeaders",
                                "namespace": "MAHN.Model",
                                "defaultResourceName": "TeamLeaders",
                                "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity"
                            },
                            "_indexMap": {
                                "1": 0
                            },
                            "_entities": [
                                {
                                    "entityAspect": {
                                        "entityState": {
                                            "_$typeName": "EntityState",
                                            "name": "Unchanged"
                                        },
                                        "isBeingSaved": false,
                                        "originalValues": {},
                                        "_validationErrors": {},
                                        "validationErrorsChanged": {
                                            "name": "validationErrorsChanged_entityAspect",
                                            "_nextUnsubKey": 1
                                        },
                                        "propertyChanged": {
                                            "name": "propertyChanged_entityAspect",
                                            "_nextUnsubKey": 1
                                        },
                                        "_entityKey": {
                                            "entityType": "TeamLeaders:#MAHN.Model",
                                            "values": [
                                                1
                                            ]
                                        },
                                        "wasLoaded": true
                                    }
                                }
                            ],
                            "_emptyIndexes": []
                        }
                    },
                    "_unattachedChildrenMap": {
                        "map": {}
                    },
                    "keyGenerator": {
                        "_tempIdMap": {},
                        "nextNumber": -1,
                        "nextNumberIncrement": -1,
                        "stringPrefix": "K_"
                    },
                    "_hasChanges": true
                },
                "entityType": {
                    "name": "User:#MAHN.Model",
                    "shortName": "User",
                    "namespace": "MAHN.Model",
                    "defaultResourceName": "Users",
                    "autoGeneratedKeyType": "Identity"
                },
                "_indexMap": {
                    "1": 2,
                    "2": 0,
                    "3": 1
                },
                "_entities": [
                    {
                        "entityAspect": {
                            "entityState": {
                                "_$typeName": "EntityState",
                                "name": "Unchanged"
                            },
                            "isBeingSaved": false,
                            "originalValues": {},
                            "_validationErrors": {},
                            "validationErrorsChanged": {
                                "name": "validationErrorsChanged_entityAspect",
                                "_nextUnsubKey": 1
                            },
                            "propertyChanged": {
                                "name": "propertyChanged_entityAspect",
                                "_nextUnsubKey": 1
                            },
                            "_entityKey": {
                                "entityType": "User:#MAHN.Model",
                                "values": [
                                    2
                                ]
                            },
                            "wasLoaded": true
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "entityAspect": {
                            "entityState": {
                                "_$typeName": "EntityState",
                                "name": "Unchanged"
                            },
                            "isBeingSaved": false,
                            "originalValues": {},
                            "_validationErrors": {},
                            "validationErrorsChanged": {
                                "name": "validationErrorsChanged_entityAspect",
                                "_nextUnsubKey": 1
                            },
                            "propertyChanged": {
                                "name": "propertyChanged_entityAspect",
                                "_nextUnsubKey": 1
                            },
                            "_entityKey": {
                                "entityType": "User:#MAHN.Model",
                                "values": [
                                    3
                                ]
                            },
                            "wasLoaded": true
                        }
                    },
                    null
                ],
                "_emptyIndexes": []
            },
            "entityState": {
                "_$typeName": "EntityState",
                "name": "Added"
            },
            "isBeingSaved": false,
            "originalValues": {},
            "_validationErrors": {},
            "validationErrorsChanged": {
                "name": "validationErrorsChanged_entityAspect",
                "_nextUnsubKey": 1
            },
            "propertyChanged": {
                "name": "propertyChanged_entityAspect",
                "_nextUnsubKey": 1
            },
            "_entityKey": {
                "entityType": "User:#MAHN.Model",
                "values": [
                    1
                ]
            },
            "wasLoaded": true
        }
    }
 ]
]
```

I cannot extract very much information out of this, but I think this special part is strange. Why is the third object in this array `null` but shows up shortly after that array with State "Added":

```
"_entities": [
                {
                    "entityAspect": {
                        "entityState": {
                            "_$typeName": "EntityState",
                            "name": "Unchanged"
                        },
                        "isBeingSaved": false,
                        "originalValues": {},
                        "_validationErrors": {},
                        "validationErrorsChanged": {
                            "name": "validationErrorsChanged_entityAspect",
                            "_nextUnsubKey": 1
                        },
                        "propertyChanged": {
                            "name": "propertyChanged_entityAspect",
                            "_nextUnsubKey": 1
                        },
                        "_entityKey": {
                            "entityType": "User:#MAHN.Model",
                            "values": [
                                2
                            ]
                        },
                        "wasLoaded": true
                    }
                },
                {
                    "entityAspect": {
                        "entityState": {
                            "_$typeName": "EntityState",
                            "name": "Unchanged"
                        },
                        "isBeingSaved": false,
                        "originalValues": {},
                        "_validationErrors": {},
                        "validationErrorsChanged": {
                            "name": "validationErrorsChanged_entityAspect",
                            "_nextUnsubKey": 1
                        },
                        "propertyChanged": {
                            "name": "propertyChanged_entityAspect",
                            "_nextUnsubKey": 1
                        },
                        "_entityKey": {
                            "entityType": "User:#MAHN.Model",
                            "values": [
                                3
                            ]
                        },
                        "wasLoaded": true
                    }
                },
                null
            ],
```

If it helps I can provide more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, there was a bug here with certain entity graphs on the server causing a spurious entityState change when serialized to the client.  This should be fixed in v0.74.2 available on the breeze website or via nuget. Please let us know if this corrects your issues.

Answer (score 1):

I have the same issue. I found that what causes this in my case was navigation property (many) included in the result. I'm still investigating this, but it looks like updateRelatedEntityInCollection() in Breeze sets "Added" when hooking up the associated objects received together with the "main" objects.

```
function updateRelatedEntityInCollection(relatedEntity, relatedEntities, targetEntity, inverseProperty) {
        if (!relatedEntity) return;
        // check if the related entity is already hooked up
        var thisEntity = relatedEntity.getProperty(inverseProperty.name);
        if (thisEntity !== targetEntity) {
            // if not - hook it up.
            relatedEntities.push(relatedEntity); // <-- THIS WILL SET "ADDED" ON targetEntity
            relatedEntity.setProperty(inverseProperty.name, targetEntity);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Great clue!  I'm hoping to receive a failing example from you and/or @Sascha.

Comment: I have just send MvcApplication2.zip to askWard. It is based on the ToDo Sample nuget.

Comment: Received it. I see what you are doing ... and why this triggers the unexpected behavior. Am writing back to you privately. When we are all clear on what's going on and what you intended, I'll summarize back here.

Comment: I didn't received your mail, but v0.74.2 fixed the problem. If there is something wrong in the way I'm using breeze, please let us know. Thank you for the quick response.

Comment: You did fine. Sorry I didn't get back to you personally. I knew 74.2 dealt with it and we thought you'd see that here. Thanks again for sending us the failing example. It really helped.

Answer (score 0):

Would like to help and I can appreciate that you're stuck. Unfortunately I can't make much progress with what you provided. Let's try again with a more simple problem statement and example.

A good start is to look at the data from a simple HTTP call to the service. Try entering something like the following in the browser address bar:  
`http://localhost:12345/api/your-service/users` 
You should see the JSON data for the three users you created.

Now try to fetch them on the client:

```
var em = new breeze.EntityManager('api/your-service');
var q = breeze.EntityQuery.from('Users')
        .using(em).execute()
        .then(querySucceeded)
        .fail(queryFailed);

function querySucceeded(data) {
    var users = data.results;
    var changes = em.getChanges();
    var msg = "User count = " + users.length +
              "; pending changes = " + changes.length;
    alert(msg);

function queryFailed(error) {
   alert('Query failed: '+error.message);
}
```

If the alert box confirms that you have 3 users and non-zero pending changes ... you have something we can sink our teeth into.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply :). 
First: The service works, i get the user. It works for all Entities i have, but it returns 'User count=3; pending changes=1'...
I have a little test-page in my SPA. A textarea with codemirror where i can enter EntityQueries and get the data per eval(string). 
Every(!) query i send, no matter what entity, always 1 has pending changes. In the query-method before the query is executed i call 'manager.rejectChanges()'. Nothing changes, still 1 pending every time. (Button triggers query,knockout prints out result). If i change the query from 'Users' to 'Teams'...

Comment: the result changes to 'pending=0' on the second query with 'Teams' and vice versa. No matter what Entity i use, always the same.

Comment: Better Example: App loads all users on start-page, shown as list. Navigating to the JSON Test-page and querying 'Teams' (`manager.rejectChanges()` before every query) pending=1 always. Switching once to start-page (requery users from server) and back to JSON Test-page. The first query for 'Teams' has pending 0. After that everything works as expected. (Not doing too much still)

Comment: I guess you're going to have to send us the example. I've never seen anything like it. Would you please strip it down to the absolute essential failing example (really important to remove all unneeded server and client code and html too). Delete the bin and obj folders. Delete the packages folder. Zip it ... and send zip with email (so I can reply) and link to this SO post to askWard at IdeaBlade dot com.  I'll see what I can make of it. Sorry for your pain.

Comment: Thank you for your reply and your offer. I have stripped almost everything from my app and tried to keep the loading in sequence and... it works normally :(. I cannot reproduce the problem with the stripped version. 'pending = 0' instantly. If i find any error or the error in the stripped version i will report here. 
Now i have to go over my entire app to find the error, i dont even know where to start. This sucks ^^
Besides that breeze takes a lot of work away and works like a charm.

Comment: I did reproduce it with the stripped version! I am packaging email now.

Answer (score 0):

I've been testing this on v 0.73.6, and making sure that the "updateRelatedEntityInCollection" methods was being called internally.

As yet, I have not been able to reproduce the issue where the entityManager.hasChanges() returns a true or EntityManager.getChanges() returns any entities as a result of any query.

I've tried using query "expands", "loadNavigationProperty", and changing the QueryOptions.MergeStrategy all without being able to repro this; so any additional hints would be very helpful.

Comment: Still waiting for the trimmed down zip sample that I requested in the comment above.

Comment: I just mailed it to you. Took a little time to do so. I stripped out a little more. The problem is not the loading sequence its the navigation properties, but you will see.

Comment: Hopefully fixed with 0.74.2.